# Getting extra characters when printing chunks of a file

Tags: python, discord.py

So I have a file that has an url on each line. I'm using discord.py to print it to a discord channel. This is my code:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
     for line in itertools.zip_longest(*[f]*10, fillvalue = ' '):
           await channel.send(line)
```

I'm using this code because Discord has a 2000 limit character on messages. I don't know how long my list is since it's updated periodically from another Python script. So I chose to make it print 10 lines at a time. Using the code above it will always print the whole file, the number of lines doesn't need to be a multiple of 10, which is exactly what I want.

The problem is that that each output message is enclosed by ( ) and it's adding /n or n%27 at the end of each item. As you can imagine that breaks the links.

What can I do do strip the results from those characters? I can live with the ( ) but the things at the end of the items need to go. Basically I want the entire content printed with items separated by " , ".

Please help. Thank you!

LE: For clarification, the input (content of the file) is like this:

```
https://www.google1.com
https://www.google2.com
https://www.google3.com
https://www.google4.com
```

The output of my code is like this:

('https://www.google1.com/n', 'https://www.google2.com/n','https://www.google3.com/n', 'https://www.google4.com/n%27)

Comment: Can you add the output?

Comment: Sure. The output of the file is like this: 
('https://www.google1.com/n', 'https://www.google2.com/n', 'https://www.google3.com/n', 'https://www.google4.com/n%27)

Answer (score 0):

So after trying several ideas, I finally managed to get it working properly. My code transformed every line it read from the file into a tuple. So everything it printed to my discord channel was a tuple hence the new line characters.

If anyone else has this problem, I fixed it by converting the tuple to a string and then printing. Now the output looks identical to the contents of my file.

The new code is this:

```
with open('myfile.txt') as f:
     for line in itertools.zip_longest(*[f]*10, fillvalue = ' '):
           x = ''.join(line)
           await channel.send(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix it by this way

```
with open("myfile.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        await channel.send(line.split('/')[0])
```